# CSS transitions in webkit

Tags: css, css-transitions, flicker

I am seeing an interesting bug in chrome regarding CSS transitions.

The page flickers during the transitions. For now i have only seen this in Chrome.

You can see this on my porfolio: www.dkhalife.com

Just scroll down to the skills sections and hover over any of the social icons on the right repeatedly, you can't miss it...

The CSS transition code is mainly :

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms;
-moz-transition: all 500ms;
-o-transition: all 500ms;
transition: all 500ms;
```

And basically i am just changing the opacity and margin using a hover pseudo class.

I have tried:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

As mentioned on some other questions on SO but it doesn't seem to fix my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms;
```

animate just the properties you want to change

```
-webkit-transition: opacity,margin 500ms;
```

Comment: wow that was it! i mean that is completely weird. is it a known issue?

Comment: @DanyKhalife never heard of it.. without digging deep into your code my first guess was that there is some value in `all` that flickers, so just narrowed the animation to desired properties and it worked as expected :)